# Setting Active Class With Javascript Date to Set Colour Scheme?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I had an idea for my website that would set the colour theme to red on Friday for Red Friday in Canada to support our troops. My website's theme has an existing skin changer with multiple skins that you can set by choosing from a list, though I don't want that menu so I removed it but kept the skins css.

This is my current attempt, it is setting the red skin as active but the page isnt updating to the colour.

```
        <div id="skin-decider-container">
            <div id="color-skin-1" class="color-skin"></div>
            <div id="color-skin-2" class="color-skin"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var decider = document.getElementById("skin-decider-container");
            var skins = decider.getElementsByClassName("color-skin");
            var d = new Date().getDay();
            console.log(d);
            if(d == 5) {
                skins[1].className += " active";
            } else {
                skins[0].className += " active";
            }

            console.log(skins[0].id + " " + skins[0].className);
            console.log(skins[1].id + " " + skins[1].className);
        </script>
```

console outputs: (correct)

```
5
color-skin-1 color-skin
color-skin-2 color-skin active
```

But the html doesnt update. Is there a way to make this update automatically?

EDIT1:

Here's the jQuery that is still at the bottom of the page that listened to the skin chooser for clicks. Any way to adapt this to be automatic?

```
               jQuery(".color-skin").click(function () {
                    var cls = this.id;
                    jQuery(".color-skin").removeClass("active");
                    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
                    jQuery("#main-wrapper").removeClass();
                    jQuery("#main-wrapper").addClass(cls);
                });
```

EDIT2:

Here's the menu I removed. I'm not seeing any onClick=

```
<div id="skin-chooser-container" class="skin-chooser-container">
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="skin-chooser hidden-xs"><i class="icon-cogs"></i></a>
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">CHOOSE COLOR SKIN</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="skins-wrapper">
                                    <ul class="list-inline">
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-1" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-2" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-3" class="color-skin active"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-4" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-5" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-6" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-7" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-8" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-9" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-10" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-11" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-12" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-13" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-14" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-15" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="color-skin-16" class="color-skin"></div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.modal-content -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal -->
            </div>
            <!-- /#skin-chooser-container -->
```

Comment: You removed all the code that does all the updates required to change your skin, but then you expect changing a class name will somehow call that code?

Comment: I removed the menu, but left the jQuery at the bottom alone. There is nothing in the menu that sets it aside from the buttons that the jQuery listens for clicks. I'm asking how I can adapt this to be automatic so I dont have to click any buttons. I'll update OP with the jQuery.

Comment: Ok, so the code would be setting up event listeners on the menu.  Find where it sets the event listeners and call whatever functions it is setting up from your code instead.  Looks like all it's doing is changing the class of `#main-wrapper`.  You could pretty much do this with: `switch(new Date().getDay()) { case 5: jQuery("#main-wrapper").removeClass().addClass('color-skin-2'); break }`

Comment: You are beautiful. Thank you! If you'd like to make this an answer then I can mark it answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu code is setting up event listeners on the menu elements. Find where it sets the event listeners and then call replicate what it is doing from your code instead.

Since the menu code is achieving the skin change by replacing the class on a single element you should be able to do the same with this:

```
switch(new Date().getDay()) {
    case 5: // friday
            jQuery("#main-wrapper").removeClass().addClass('color-skin-2'); 
            break;
}
```